# Actualizar marcador en tiempo real en google maps con javascript tipo uber

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Amigos, llevo unos dias intentando solucionar este problema.
Tengo un mapa, en el cual traza una ruta entre 2 direcciones. Ademas de eso, la idea es ir mostrando en tiempo real donde esta el repartidor. Para ello, use un marcador, puede agregar el marcador al mapa cuando se inicia, pero no tengo ni idea como poder ir actualizando ese marcador sin tener que actualizar el mapa completo. En el panel del repartidor se ira enviando la ubicacion en tiempo real con las coordenas y las recibira en maps, como podria crear una funcion pasandole longitud y latitud?

Les dejo el link en codepen para que puedan ver el ejemplo en vivo: https://codepen.io/Maikel-Yordan/pen/ZEVGBpx

Gracias!